# XML, XSD, XSL to HTML

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xsd

I am stuck with a job. I have to make a listing in XML, XSD and XSL and have it displayed in a HTML, separated. I mean, that each one has its own space. MAIN, ASIDE and FOOTER.
I'm going crazy and have given it a thousand thought. I don't know where I'm going wrong. I have touched the code so many times that the original has been lost and I had to rescue a backup copy. I would appreciate your help.

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <html><head>
            <style type="text/css">
            table, th,td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

             {
        
             }
        </style>
        </head><body>
        <h1><strong> Fulgur Domun </strong></h1>           
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body></html>
        </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="TV">
            <table> 
                    <tr bgcolor="#4dd0e1">
                        <th>Departamento</th>  
                        <th>Marca</th> 
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Medidas</th>
                        <th>Conexion</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                    </tr> 
                <xsl:for-each select="/TV/articulo">
                <xsl:sort select="precio"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#4dd0e1"><xsl:value-of select="departamento"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="marca"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="medidas"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="conexion"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="precio"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <img width="50px" name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="imagen"/>
                            </img>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="AUDIO">        
            <table>
                    <tr bgcolor="#4dd0e1">
                        <th>Departamento</th>  
                        <th>Marca</th> 
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Medidas</th>
                        <th>Conexion</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                    </tr> 
                <xsl:for-each select="/AUDIO/articulo">
                <xsl:sort select="precio"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#4dd0e1"><xsl:value-of select="departamento"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="marca"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="medidas"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="conexion"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="precio"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <img width="50px" name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="imagen"/>
                            </img>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ACCESORIOS">
            <table>
                    <tr bgcolor="#4dd0e1">
                        <th>Departamento</th>  
                        <th>Marca</th> 
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Medidas</th>
                        <th>Conexion</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                    </tr> 
                <xsl:for-each select="/ACCESORIOS/articulo">
                <xsl:sort select="precio"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#4dd0e1"><xsl:value-of select="departamento"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="marca"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="medidas"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="conexion"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="precio"/></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ff8f00"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <img width="50px" name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="imagen"/>
                            </img>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table> 
        </xsl:template>  
       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="articulos.xsl"?>
<tienda>
<TV>
    <articulo>
        <departamento>marron</departamento>
        <marca>LG</marca>
        <modelo>55 utf 1500</modelo>
        <medidas>55"</medidas>
        <conexion>4k</conexion>
        <precio>1499€</precio>
        <color>Plata</color>
        <imagen>/img/tvlg.jpg</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>marron</departamento>
        <marca>Samsung</marca>
        <modelo>55 Q60T</modelo>
        <medidas>55"</medidas>
        <conexion>4K</conexion>
        <precio>819€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/TVSAMS.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>marron</departamento>
        <marca>Sony</marca>
        <modelo>65 KD-65AG9</modelo>
        <medidas>65"</medidas>
        <conexion>8K</conexion>
        <precio>2999€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/TVSONY.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>marron</departamento>
        <marca>Philips</marca>
        <modelo>65MK-O40</modelo>
        <medidas>65"</medidas>
        <conexion>8K</conexion>
        <precio>1999€</precio>
        <color>Blanco</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/TVPHIL.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

  
    <articulo>
        <departamento>marron</departamento>
        <marca>Panasonic</marca>
        <modelo>TX-JZjz1500e</modelo>
        <medidas>48"</medidas>
        <conexion>4K</conexion>
        <precio>1199€</precio>
        <color>Plata</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/TVPANA.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>
</TV>

<AUDIO>
    
    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca>Panasonic</marca>
        <modelo>SC-PM250EC</modelo>
        <medidas>30x40</medidas>
        <conexion>20w</conexion>
        <precio>99,99€</precio>
        <color>Gris</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/HIFIPANA.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>


    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca>Sony</marca>
        <modelo>MHC-V11</modelo>
        <medidas>40x20</medidas>
        <conexion>2x30w</conexion>
        <precio>199,99€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/HIFISONY.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>


    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca>LG</marca>
        <modelo>OK55</modelo>
        <medidas>90x30</medidas>
        <conexion>500w</conexion>
        <precio>259</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/HIFILG.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>


    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca>Sony</marca>
        <modelo>CMT-SBT20</modelo>
        <medidas>Si</medidas>
        <conexion>30x40</conexion>
        <precio>99</precio>
        <color>Plata</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/HIFISONY_2.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca>Phillips</marca>
        <modelo>MCM 2300/12</modelo>
        <medidas>No</medidas>
        <conexion>10x20</conexion>
        <precio>99,99€</precio>
        <color>Gris</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/HIFIPHIL.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>HIFI</departamento>
        <marca> Denon </marca>
        <modelo> Ceol Piccolo N5 </modelo>
        <medidas> Si </medidas>
        <conexion>40x30</conexion>
        <precio> 1793,35€ </precio>
        <color>Blanco</color>
        <imagen>/Img/HIFIDENON.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>
</AUDIO>

<ACCESORIOS>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Ardistel</marca>
        <modelo>ViNint83</modelo>
        <medidas>2m</medidas>
        <conexion>hdmi</conexion>
        <precio>50.06€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLARDIS.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Hama</marca>
        <modelo>00205005</modelo>
        <medidas>1,50m</medidas>
        <conexion>HDMI</conexion>
        <precio>12,99€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>   
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLHAMA.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Hama</marca>
        <modelo>0056581</modelo>
        <medidas>2m</medidas>
        <conexion>Antena</conexion>
        <precio>12,99€</precio>
        <color>Blanco</color>   
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLHAMA_ANTENA.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Star Tech</marca>
        <modelo>HD2VGAMM3n</modelo>
        <medidas>0,90m</medidas>
        <conexion>DVI</conexion>
        <precio>35,99€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLSTARTECH.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Woxter</marca>
        <modelo>w-31544-rusb</modelo>
        <medidas>15m</medidas>
        <conexion>RGB</conexion>
        <precio>19,99€</precio>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLWOXTER.JPG</imagen>
       
    </articulo>

    <articulo>
        <departamento>CABLEADO</departamento>
        <marca>Red Level</marca>
        <modelo>M-dt2</modelo>
        <medidas>5m</medidas>
        <conexion>HDMI</conexion>
        <precio>50.06€</precio>
        <color>Blanco</color>
        <imagen>/IMG/CABLREDLEV.JPG</imagen>
    </articulo>
</ACCESORIOS>


</tienda>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="TV">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="departamento" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="medidas" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="conexion" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="precio" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/> 
                <xs:element name="imagen" type="xs:hexBinary"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="AUDIO">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="departamento" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="medidas" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="conexion" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="precio" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/> 
                <xs:element name="imagen" type="xs:hexBinary"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="ACCESORIOS">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="departamento" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="modelo" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="medidas" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="conexion" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="precio" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/> 
                <xs:element name="imagen" type="xs:hexBinary"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: where are your xml

Comment: I forgott to add. Finally, there it is.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify what is the input and what is the expected output. If the output needs to be HTML, post the exact HTML code you expect to get.

Comment: check following code for-each

 <xsl:for-each select="//TV/articulo">

 <xsl:for-each select="//AUDIO/articulo">

<xsl:for-each select="//ACCESORIOS/articulo">